# Difference between making an operation in a new variable and making it in the println statement

Tags: java

Is there any difference between the two? I am always talking about the "back-end" of the program, difference in program size etc.

Do the operation in a new variable and then print the new variable value:

```
int returned = x*y;
System.out.println(returned);
```

Do the operation directly in the println statement:

```
System.out.println(x*y);
```

Comment: In the first example you'll have an extra variable that will be destroyed by the GC. The performance difference is too small to notice. It's better to focus on readability and such.

Answer (score -1):

The first one consumes more memory because Java has to allocate memory to store the variable, but that is the only difference I see.
See this for more info : https://dzone.com/articles/java-memory-management

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so there is no performance difference at all? Only the memory that it will consume which in this case is 4bytes? (since it is an integer)